# appending multiple values to CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to append two variables tonename and score to the CSV output (code below will only append tone_name) but not sure how to do it, I would really appreciate any help here:

```
for fle in file:
    # open the file and then call .read() to get the text 
    with open(fle) as f:
        text = f.read

    # tone analysis
    data=tone_analyzer.tone(text='text')

    # iterate through tone analysis data
    tonename=[]; tonescore=[]
    for cat in data['document_tone']['tone_categories']:
        for tone in cat['tones']:
             tonename.append(tone['tone_name'])
             tonescore.append(tone['score'])
             print(tone['tone_name'],tone['score'])

    # output tone name and score to file
    output = fle.replace('.txt', '')     
    X=output
        with open(X+'_tonename.csv', mode = 'w') as csvfile1:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile1) 
    for Y in range(len(tonename)):
     writer.writerow(tonename[Y] + ',' tonescore[Y])
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating through tonename you could find the len of tonename and iterate through both tonename & score

```
for x in range(len(tonename)):
  writer.writerow(tonename[x] + ',' + tonescore[x])
```

Comment: Thank You, I just changed the code (see edited by now I am getting an error invalid syntax

Comment: THanks again, it is pointing to last line:  writer.writerow(tonename[Y] + ',' tonescore[Y])

Comment: I seem to have made a typo and you diligently copied it.  Try `writer.writerow(tonename[Y] + ',' + tonescore[Y])`

Comment: Thank you so much for your continuous help but now I am getting a error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

Comment: that would mean that for some reason `Y` is returning a string ... try commenting out writer.writerow and replace it with `print(Y)` and `print(tonescore[Y])`

Comment: Thank you, i got the same error again the values for score like this : 0.571, 0.817   and so on.

Comment: which print line did it error on?  can you repost your code?